# Can I apply new layers of cleat coat on top of old and what preparation steps are needed?

Tags: paint, body-work, paint-clearcoat

I used aerosol painting kit purchased on automotivetouchup.com, and while base color matched well, their "Aerosol High Gloss Clear Coat" does not seemed to be of the highest quality, it does not make glossiest mirror-like surface which I need to match with rest of my car surface, it's rather matte, and polishing does not help a lot really. I also tried it on test flat surfaces, and got the same results. I believe I followed all rules and recommendations while painting and clear coating.

I made some research including this forum, and found that results depends a lot on quality of Clear Coat, and people recommend SprayMax 2K Clearcoat. I wonder if I can save my painting work and apply SprayMax on top of old clear coat, and what preparation steps do I need to take, like wet sanding maybe? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to lightly sand the clear coat so the new clear coat and adhere

Comment: like 1500 grit?

Comment: that would work